# I can't get my crontab to work

Tags: 16.04, cron

I have the following crontab file (as root):

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
indicating with different fields when the task will be run
and what command to run for the task
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# m h  dom mon dow   command

1 * * * *  echo "test" >> /tmp/testing.txt
```

The problem is that the command is never executed. I can see in `/var/log/syslog` that the file has been edited:

```
May 25 17:51:57 XXXX crontab[5010]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
May 25 17:52:26 XXXX crontab[5010]: (root) REPLACE (root)
May 25 17:52:26 XXXX crontab[5010]: (root) END EDIT (root)
```

When I run `crontab -l` I can see the file.

```
Cron service is running
```

I've checked the `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` and the file root is there:

```
drwx-wx--T 2 root crontab 4096 May 25 17:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root    4096 Mar 17  2017 ..
-rw------- 1 root crontab 1384 May 25 17:53 root
```

and it has the proper content. I've rebooted the server, and still no luck.

Can anyone please guide me in the right direction, please?

Comment: Removed the commented lines from crontab, still no luck..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few lines in your crontab that are supposed to be comments but don't have a leading `#` in front.
In a comment you said this is just wrong in your post and removing them didn't help.

The line

```
1 * * * *  echo "test" >> /tmp/testing.txt
```

looks fine but it means

> run the given command every hour, every day ***at minute 1***, i.e. at
>   12:01, 13:01, 14:01, 15:01, etc.

You would need to wait until that time is reached. If you want to run your job *every minute*
you need a star `*` in the minutes field as well:

```
* * * * *  echo "test" >> /tmp/testing.txt
```

This will run every minute. I found [this online editor](https://crontab.guru/#1_*_*_*_*) helpful to see what a certain
pattern means.

Comment: Wow.... What a mistake from my site... Im so sorry that i posted this, but you are absolutely right.

Comment: @Mikkel Don't worry, crontab's syntax is not exactly intuitive for me either.